Can I put my daughter back on my taxes after she filed years before on her own?
My daughter is 21 and filed her own taxes in the years before because she made more than the free amount.
2022 she still lived with me but has not earned anything. Does she still need to file her own return, or can I put her back on my tax return?

Note that whether she files a tax return and whether she is your dependent are two separate things. A dependent can still file a tax return; they would just check the box on form 1040 that says someone can claim them as a dependent.

What jurisdiction are you in? Tax laws vary around the world.

Just to clear up some terminology, one can still file a return and still be claimed as a dependent on someone else's tax return. This is common for children that earn income and are still "dependents" on their parent's return.  So by "put her back on my tax return" I assume you mean "claim her as a dependent", which has little to do with whether or not she has to file a return.
If she did not earn anything, she probably doesn't need to file a tax return - but she can check the requirements to be certain. That doesn't mean that she can be claimed as a dependent on your taxes, though.
The rules for a qualifying child are pretty clear:

Qualifying child
To qualify as a dependent, a child must also pass these tests:

Relationship: Be your son, daughter, stepchild, eligible foster child, brother, sister, half-sister or -brother, stepbrother,
stepsister, adopted child or the child of one of these
Age: Be under age 19 or under 24 if a full-time student, or any age if permanently and totally disabled
Residency: Live with you for more than half the year, with some exceptions
Support: Get more than half their financial support from you
Joint return: Not file as married filing jointly unless only to claim a refund of taxes paid or withheld


However, she may still qualify as a Quafilying Relative:

Qualifying relative
A qualifying relative must meet general rules for dependents and pass
these tests:

Not a qualifying child: Isn't your qualifying child or the qualifying child of any other taxpayer
Member of household or relationship: Lives with you all year as a member of your household or is a specific type of relative
Gross income: Has gross income under $4,700
Support: Gets more than half their financial support from you


If she lived with you all year and made less than $4,700, she might be a qualifying relative that you can claim as a dependent.

"So unless she is a full-time student or disabled, she is not a dependent" This is incorrect. You don't need to be a "qualifying child" to be a dependent. A dependent can also be a "qualifying relative". Even an adult who is not related to you can be a dependent, if they meet the conditions.

@user102008 Thanks - I forgot that part.
